# How can I install Internet Explorer in Linux?

Tags: linux, installation, internet-explorer

How can I install Internet Explorer in Linux?

Answer (score 9):

You can try [ies4linux](http://www.tatanka.com.br/ies4linux/page/Main_Page).

Beware though that they may not work as expected. In my personal experience, I had some problems using it. The best way to test how websites behave in these browsers is using a virtual machine with windows and IE's installed.

Answer (score 6):

Your best bet is going to be to use a VM with Windows installed. None of the alternatives ever worked well at all.

Comment: +1. Multi-IE hacks under any platform are never quite the same as the real thing. It's usually okay for a quick layout check, but for anything complex involving scripting VMs are the only reliable solution.

Answer (score 3):

[How To Install Microsoft Internet Explorer on Linux in Two Easy Steps](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-to-install-internet-explorer-on-linux.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could also look at installing [wine](http://www.winehq.org/), the Windows emulator, and then installing IE under that.