# How can I install Internet Explorer in Linux?

Tags: linux, internet-explorer, centos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to install internet explorer in linux](https://superuser.com/questions/40945/how-to-install-internet-explorer-in-linux)

How to install Internet Explorer in CentOS? What are the supporting files to be installed for that?

Comment: Look in to using Wine. http://wiki.jswindle.com/index.php/Internet_Explorer

Comment: I would think the biggest issue here would be licensing;  Is it possible to do this legally?

Answer (score 1):

IES4Linux - http://www.tatanka.com.br/ies4linux/page/Main_Page

That worked for me the last time I wanted to use IE for testing.